# Are random intervals predictable?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let

- $T>0$
- $I:=[0,T]$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in I}$ be a filtration of $\mathcal A$, $$\mathcal R:=\bigcup_{F\in\mathcal F_0}F\times\left\{0\right\}\cup\bigcup_{0\le s<t\le T}\bigcup_{F\in\mathcal F_s}F\times(s,t]$$ and $$\mathcal P:=\sigma(\mathcal R)$$
- $\tau:\Omega\to I$ be an $\mathcal F$-stopping time

> Are we able to show that $$X(\omega,t):=1_{\left\{\:t\:\le\:\tau(\omega)\:\right\}}\;\;\;\text{for }(\omega,t)\in\Omega\times I$$ is $\mathcal P$-measurable?

Since $$\left\{\omega\in\Omega:t\le\tau(\omega)\right\}=\Omega\setminus\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\tau(\omega)<t\right\}\in\mathcal F_t\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in I\;,\tag1$$ it's clear that $(X(\;\cdot\;,t))_{t\in I}$ is $\mathcal F$-adapted. The desired claim should be equivalent to $$[0,\tau]:=\left\{(\omega,t)\in\Omega\times I:t\le\tau(\omega)\right\}\in\mathcal P\;.\tag2$$ How can we prove that?

Comment: A standard idea would be to approximate $\tau$ from above by a sequence $(\tau_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ of discrete stopping times (by "discrete" I mean that $\tau_j$ takes only countably many values).

Comment: @saz Why this should yield the desired result?

Comment: What do you mean....? Have you given it a try?

Comment: @saz I don't get the idea behind the approximation, but first of all: How do you choose the approximating sequence? If the filtration in question would be defined over the time interval $[0,∞)$, then we simply could choose $$τ_n:=\frac1{2^n}\lceil 2^nτ\rceil\;\;\;\text{for }n\inℕ\;.$$ Then, $τ_n\in\frac1{2^n}ℕ_0\cup\left\{∞\right\}$ and $τ_n$ is an $(\mathcal F_{k2^{-n}})_{k\inℕ_0}$-stopping time for all $n\inℕ$, $(τ_n)_{n\inℕ}$ is nondecreasing and $τ_n\xrightarrow{n→∞}τ$. But here the filtration is defined over $[0,T]$ and $τ_n$ as defined above would take values outside of $[0,T]$.

Comment: In order to avoid this problem, you could simply arrange it that $\tau_n$ takes values in $\frac{T}{2^n} \mathbb{N}_0$ (and not $\frac{1}{2^n} \mathbb{N}_0$), right? Regarding the idea: For a discrete stopping time $\tau$ the random interval $[0,\tau]$ is somewhat nicer than for a general stopping time.

Comment: @saz You're right. We could either replace $τ_n$ by $τ_n\wedge T$ or (and I guess that's what you got in mind) replace $τ_n$ by $$τ_n:=\frac T{2^n}\lceil\frac{2^n}Tτ\rceil\;.$$ With this definition, $τ_n$ is an $\left(\mathcal F_{k\frac T{2^n}}\right)_{k∈\left\{0,\:…\:,\:2^n\right\}}$-stopping time with $τ_n↓τ$. Now, $$[0,τ_n]=\biguplus_{k=0}^{2^n}\left\{(ω,t)∈\left\{τ_n=k\frac T{2^n}\right\}× I:t\le k\frac T{2^n}\right\}=\biguplus_{k=0}^{2^n}\underbrace{\left\{τ_n=k\frac T{2^n}\right\}}_{∈\:\mathcal F_{k\frac T{2^n}}}×\left[0,k\frac T{2^n}\right]\;.$$ But these sets aren't in $\mathcal R$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity of notation we consider only $T=1$. If we define a sequence of stopping times by

$$\tau_n := \frac{ \lfloor 2^n \tau \rfloor +1}{2^n}$$

then $\tau_n \downarrow \tau$ and $\{\tau_n \leq k 2^{-n}\} \in \mathcal{F}_{k2^{-n}}$. In particular,

$$[0,\tau] = \bigcap_{n \geq 1} [0,\tau_n]$$

and therefore it suffices to show that $[0,\tau_n]$ is predictable for all $n \geq 1$. To this end, note that

$$\tau_n(\omega)> (k-1)2^{-n} \implies \tau_n(\omega) \geq k2^{-n}$$

and so

$$[0,\tau_n] = \left( \{0\} \times \Omega \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{2^n} ((k-1)2^{-n},k2^{-n}] \times \{\tau_n>(k-1)2^{-n}\} \right).$$

As

$$\{\tau_n > (k-1)2^{-n}\} = \{\tau_n \leq (k-1)2^{-n}\}^c \in \mathcal{F}_{(k-1)2^{-n}}$$

this proves that $[0,\tau_n]$ is predictable.